# Prevent sharing of adder logic

Tags: vhdl, quartus, synthesis

Suppose the following VHDL component:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    port
    (
        iClk : in std_logic;

        iDataA : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
        iDataB : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
        iDataC : in unsigned(7 downto 0);

        oResultA : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
        oResultB : out unsigned(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behaviour of adder is
begin
    process
    begin
        wait until rising_edge(iClk);
        if iDataB /= 0 then
            oResultA <= iDataA + iDataB;
        else
            oResultB <= iDataA + iDataC;
        end if;
    end process;
end behaviour;
```

As it can be seen it contains two additions. I expected that the synthesized logic would also contain two adders. Instead Quartus seems to think it’s a good idea to use only a single adder and mux the second input to it (see RTL below). In my opinion this does not make any sense. It saves no hardware resources because the mux requires the same number of logic elements as the adder would have required. Additionally the mux needs to wait until the if condition is evaluated, which results in worse timing.

I’ve had this happen with a much larger component and a large state machine, which lead to timing violations. How do I prevent this sort of “optimization”? I’ve set the optimization mode to “Performace (Aggressive – increases runtime and area)”, but it doesn’t seem to make a difference. The only thing which lead to the expected result was to introduce additional signals like so:

```
tmpA <= iDataA + iDataB;
tmpB <= iDataA + iDataC;

process
begin
    wait until rising_edge(iClk);
    if iDataB /= 0 then
        oResultA <= tmpA;
    else
        oResultB <= tmpB;
    end if;
end process;
```

Is there a better way to do this, as it makes the code really hard to read. I'm using Quartus 20.1 with a Max10 FPGA.

RTL view:
[image]

Comment: "In my opinion this does not make any sense." Your readers might be more comfortable with a demonstration this is either reflected in logic element utilization or performance. There are device families where the multiplexer might be 'free' based on LUT size used for each adder element. Your second snippet elaborates to two processes for the two concurrent assignment statements providing separate mapping effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that an option (in Advanced Synthsizer Settings) called "Auto Resource Sharing" is off. Resource sharing enables a synthesiser to do this adder-sharing that you want not to do.

OR

Put your adders in a different layer of hierarchy (ie in a separate entity) and then set an attribute to prevent it being optimised called *keep*:

```
attribute keep: boolean;
attribute keep of my_adder0: label is true;
attribute keep of my_adder1: label is true;
```

where `my_adder0` and `my_adder1` are the labels of your adder instances.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the option I was looking for. Do you know if Synthesis Settings like this option can be set for individual VHDL files? I'm kind of scared when I enable this option globally for my almost full project.

Comment: @sebi707 I don't know, sorry. However, it is possible to synthesise your design in parts. This is common with IC designs, because generally they are bigger. So, if you run Quartus from a script, you could turn this option off when you synthesise this block, and on when you synthesise the other blocks.